# Mirthconnector : How to convert nested json to csv using mirth connector

Tags: mirth-connect

I need to convert the JSON file to CSV using mirth connector. I am very new to mirth connector could you please help me.

I have created the channel and i have written the below code which is giving my output in single line.

Code:

```
for each (element in jsonObject) 
    {
        var row = <row/>;
        var col = <row/>;
        for (var key1 in element) 
            {if (typeof element[key1] != 'object')
                {
                    row[key1] = element[key1].toString();
                    col[key1] = key1;
                }
                    for (var key2 in element[key1])

            {if (typeof element[key1][key2] != 'object')
                {
                row[key1+key2] = element[key1][key2].toString();
                col[key1+key2] = key1+'.'+key2;
                }

             }
            }


msg.appendChild(col);

msg.appendChild(row);
}
```

Input:

```
{
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
        "hex": "#00F"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#0F0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To begin with, there is no such thing as Mirth Connect**or**. It's called Mirth Connect. Learn the tool you are using.

Comment: what version of mirth you are using?

Comment: The version i am using is 3.5.1